# Glossaries package: capitalise first word of sentence in list of acronyms

Tags: glossaries

I have seen many similar but slightly different questions on the capitalisation of glossary entries or acronyms in the text itself and in the list of acronyms, but none answered my question: **How do I capitalise only the first word of a sentence in the list of acronyms, while keeping the acronyms in the text lower case?**

**MWE (default behaviour):**

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[acronyms,nomain]{glossaries-extra}

\makeglossaries
\setabbreviationstyle[acronym]{long-short}

\newacronym{UAV}{UAV}{uninhabited aerial vehicle}

\begin{document}

\printglossaries

\section{Section}

Small \glspl{UAV} [...]

\end{document}
```

produces everything in lower case:
[image: MWE]

But I want the "u" in "uninhabited" to be in upper case.

Answer (score 1):

**Solution:**

The solution is to include `\glssetcategoryattribute{acronym}{glossdesc}{firstuc}`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[acronyms,nomain]{glossaries-extra}

\makeglossaries
\setabbreviationstyle[acronym]{long-short}
\glssetcategoryattribute{acronym}{glossdesc}{firstuc}

\newacronym{UAV}{UAV}{uninhabited aerial vehicle}

\begin{document}

\printglossaries

\section{Section}

Small \glspl{UAV} [...]

\end{document}
```

[image]